# Enviar Array de objetos para Bulkcreate

Tags: node.js, react

Estou utilizando Node JS (backend) com sequelize 4.4.2 e preciso enviar um array de objetos do meu front (React JS) porém não consigo gerar no formato que é o esperado, só para comentar quando fiz um teste (hardcode) deu certo inseriu os dados.

Array esperado:

```
const listValues = **[
        {id: 0, idusuario: 2, idprofissional: 1, ativo: 1},
        {id: 0, idusuario: 2, idprofissional: 2, ativo: 1}
        ];**
```

Já tentei JSON.parse, JSON.stringify, tanto no Front como principalmente no back, acredito que pela falta ainda de conhecimento pleno em Arrays, JSON, estes formatos estou errando em algo.

Resultado que chega no BackEnd:

```
 { '{"id":0,"idusuario":1,"idprofissional":1,"ativo":1},{"id":0,"idusuario":1,"idprofissional":2,"ativo":1}': '' }
```

Parte do código que gera o array e envia para o back:

```
 save() {
        let self = this;
        let listAgenda = [];
        self.state.listProfissional.map((e, index) => {
            let agenda = {};
            agenda.id = e.id;
            agenda.idusuario = e.idusuario;
            agenda.idprofissional = e.idprofissional;
            agenda.ativo = e.ativo;
            listAgenda.push(agenda);
        });
...
```

Este listAgenda é enviado para o backend, mas ao visualizar pelo console notei que o formato muda, tenho as seguintes configurações e já tentei alterar, comentar mas nada adianta, achando que o backEnd falta algo:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Rota no backEnd responsável pela inserção:

```
app.route("/agendaprofissional/insertupdate")
    .all(app.auth.authenticate())           
    .post((req, res) => {       
        let options = {validate: true, individualHooks: true};
        console.log("req.body: ", req.body);
        AgendaProfissional.bulkCreate(req.body, options)
        .then(result => {
            if(result){
                res.json(result);
            }
            else{
                res.sendStatus(404);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.status(412).json({msg: error.message});         
        });
    })
```

Em resumo é isto, se alguém puder me orientar, mostrar o erro, como chegar no resultado que deu certo, já tentei fazer envio através de string, tipo montar o formato, mas deu erro!

Answer (score 0):

Vou tentar traduzir pra vc rapidamente o que chegou no server, isso aqui:

```
{
    '{"id":0,"idusuario":1,"idprofissional":1,"ativo":1},
{"id":0,"idusuario":1,"idprofissional":2,"ativo":1}': ''
}
```

É nada mais nada menos que um objeto com uma propriedade chamada `'{"id":0,"idusuario":1,"idprofissional":1,"ativo":1},
    {"id":0,"idusuario":1,"idprofissional":2,"ativo":1}'` com o valor `''`.

Existem dois problemas no seu método `save`, primeiro aqui:

```
self.state.listProfissional.map((e, index) => {
```

E o outro aqui:

```
listAgenda.push(agenda);
```

O método `map`, funciona assim: Ele executa a função que vc passa para ele como argumento, em cada indice da sua array e ele te da três parâmetros, respectivamente, 
**o valor** do índice, **o número** do índice e **a array** que está executando o `map`. Pelo que vi, isso vc já sacou.

O que você talvez não tenha percebido ou não saiba é que, vc tem que retornar o valor que vc **"mapeou"** no fim do método que vc passa como argumento para o `map`. E outra coisa, quando o `map` termina, ele vai retornar pra vc, uma array nova com os valores mapeados.

Então a maneira certa de vc usar esse save, seria mais ou menos essa aqui:

```
save() {
  const listAgenda = this.state.listProfissional.map(e => ({
    id: e.id,
    idusuario: e.idusuario,
    idprofissional: e.idprofissional,
    ativo: e.ativo
  }))
}
```

Ah e mais uma coisa, evite usar `self = this`, isso é desnecessário pq já existe meios de vc passar o escopo que vc quiser pra dentro de um bloco de função ok? Neste caso ai (provavelmente em nenhum outro), vc não precisa fazer isso.

Comment: Jan Cássio muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas continuo com o problema, não insere os dados, fiz as alterações que me orientou, porém não chega a requisição (req.body) para o meu backend da forma que necessito, no caso um Array of Objects, se eu acrescento JSON.stringify(listAgenda) chega no back mas dá erro, sem o stringify o req.body fica ['',''] Estou tentando obrigado novamente